# How does Mordo come to believe The Ancient One draws power from the Dark Dimension?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange-2016

At first, Mordo doesn't believe Strange when he claims The Ancient One draws power from the Dark Dimension.

However, when The Ancient One appears in the Mirror Dimension, Mordo changes his view immediately. Why is that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The same symbol that Kaecilius and his disciples bear shows up on her forehead in that scene.

[image]

Between that and her sheer strength in manipulating the mirror dimension (which Kaecilius and company also had), it was pretty conclusive that she was pulling the same power they were.

Comment: Nice catch! I didn't catch that; the movie didn't explicitly mention the symbol. You knew it from the movie or some other source?

Comment: @KinzleB - I caught it from the movie - there's a better shot than this one that gave a clearer view of her face just as the mark starts to show, and that shot coincided with Mordo's realization.  Dunno why she's not falling apart from the eyeballs out like the rest though.  Might just be a matter of degrees.

Comment: @Radhil maybe an abundance of caution on her part, or that she has a greater amount of control over it & its influence. It's pretty important to her that the source of her power is kept secret from her disciples I imagine.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "raw" power? Power that is not trained?

Comment: @KinzleB - clarified.

Comment: My impression was that she was channeling the energy without saying allegiance to Dormammu, and thus less corruption. The symbol also shows up at the end, on a window by Dr Strange.

Comment: @Radhil I figure it didn't mess with her because she was tapping into it differently than the others. It's clear that it was a fine-line-could-snap-at-any-moment kind of thing. That's why she hid it, didn't teach it, and was good at it because she'd been doing it for centuries.